# Keep amcharts series from overlapping

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts

I have a chart setup with three series that each have their own y-axis. Currently they are displaying on either side of the graph, as shown here:
[image: Current Graph]

This is a little busier than I would like the graph to be, as sometimes the series can mix together. How can I make it so that the y-axes don't overlap, something like the following:
[image: Desired Graph]

Edit: Here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/m4d-m4x/pen/PXrxXp?editors=1010)

```
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Apply chart themes
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  'timeUnit': 'second',
  'count': 1
};
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('minute', 'h:mm a');
dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = '[bold]MM-dd-yy, h:mm:ss a[/]';
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();


var data = [
  {name:'value1', value: 2, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 8, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 4, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 2, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 9, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 11, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 6, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 4, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 13, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 1, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 7, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 11, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
];
var names = ['value1','value2', 'value3'];

names.forEach((name, index) => {
  var opposite = index % 2 == 0;
  var series = this.chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  var yAxis = this.chart.yAxes.getIndex(index);
  series.yAxis = yAxis;
  series.name = name;
  series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
  series.dataFields.valueY = 'value';
  series.data = data.filter(d => d.name === name).map( d => {
    return {date: new Date(d.timestamp), value: d.value};
  });
  switch (name) {
    case 'value1':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#9E842F');
      yAxis.minY = 0;
      yAxis.maxY = 31;
      break;
    case 'value2':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#196D6F');
      yAxis.minY = -20;
      yAxis.maxY = 80;
      break;
    case 'value3':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#553786');
      yAxis.minY = 0;
      yAxis.maxY = 100;
      break;
  }
  series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
  series.tooltip.background.fill = series.stroke;
  series.tooltipText = '{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]';

  yAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
  yAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
  yAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
  yAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
  yAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
  yAxis.renderer.opposite = opposite;
  yAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
  bullet.width = 5;
  bullet.height = 5;
  bullet.fill = series.stroke;
});

var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.series.values.forEach(s => {
  scrollbarX.series.push(s);
});
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
chart.scrollbarX.parent = this.chart.bottomAxesContainer;

chart.validateData();
```

Comment: can you add a link to a working example ?

Comment: Do you not want to create 3 separate charts? Seems like that could be an pretty easy solution.

Comment: I do not want to create 3 separate charts for 2 reasons:
1. I only want to show 1 X-Axis
2. I am using a cursor on this graph that would probably be difficult to implement across three graphs. If you hover over a x-value at a specific time you can see the all of the series y-values in a tooltip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this without creating separate charts, however if you create separate charts as sub container objects within the same div, you can sync the cursor and zoom across each instance. There is an example of this right in the [github repo](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/tree/master/dist/script/examples/javascript/syncing-cursors-and-zoom) where it creates three separate instances and uses events to sync cursors together.

Demo reproduced below using your data:

```js
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

var container = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4core.Container);
container.width = am4core.percent(100);
container.height = am4core.percent(100);
container.layout = "vertical";



var chartCount = 3;
var data = [
  {name:'value1', value: 2, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 8, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 4, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 2, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 9, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 11, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 6, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 4, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 13, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 1, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 7, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 11, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
];
var charts = [];
var cursorShowDisposers = [];

// create chart instances
for (var i = 0; i < chartCount; i++) {
  makeChart(data.filter((x) => x.name == 'value' + (i + 1)), 'value' + (i + 1));
}

let legend = new am4charts.Legend();
legend.parent = container;
legend.interactionsEnabled = false;
legend.data = [{
  "name": "value1",
  "fill":"#9E842F"
}, {
  "name": "value2",
  "fill": "#196D6F"
}, {
  "name": "value3",
  "fill": "#553786"
}];

initCursorListeners();

// after the charts are made, add scrollbar to the first one
var firstChart = charts[0];
firstChart.scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
firstChart.zoomOutButton.disabled = false;

// enable date axis labels for the last one
var lastChart = charts[charts.length - 1];
var lastDateAxis = lastChart.xAxes.getIndex(0);
lastDateAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = false;
lastDateAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = true;



// create chart
function makeChart(data, name) {
  var chart = container.createChild(am4charts.XYChart);
  charts.push(chart);

  chart.data = data;
  chart.zoomOutButton.disabled = true;
  chart.padding(10, 15, 10, 15);

  var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
  dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
  dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;
  dateAxis.tooltip.animationDuration = 0; 
  dateAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
  dateAxis.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = 'i';
  dateAxis.baseInterval = {
    'timeUnit': 'second',
    'count': 1
  };
  
  var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
  valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
  valueAxis.renderer.minWidth = 60;
  
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  series.dataFields.dateX = "timestamp";
  series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
  series.name = name;
  series.interpolationDuration = 0;

  switch (name) {
    case 'value1':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#9E842F');
      valueAxis.minY = 0;
      valueAxis.maxY = 31;
      break;
    case 'value2':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#196D6F');
      valueAxis.minY = -20;
      valueAxis.maxY = 80;
      break;
    case 'value3':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#553786');
      valueAxis.minY = 0;
      valueAxis.maxY = 100;
      break;
  }
  series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
  series.tooltip.background.fill = series.stroke;
  series.tooltipText = '{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]';

  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
  bullet.width = 5;
  bullet.height = 5;
  bullet.fill = series.stroke;
  
  var cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
  cursor.lineY.disabled = true;
  cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;
  chart.cursor = cursor;


  // whenever any of the charts is zoomed, we should zoom all other charts
  dateAxis.events.on("selectionextremeschanged", function (event) {
    syncDateAxes(event.target);
  })
}


function initCursorListeners() {
  cursorShowDisposers = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var cursor = chart.cursor;
    cursor.interactionsEnabled = true;

    cursorShowDisposers.push(cursor.events.on("shown", function (event) {
      handleShowCursor(event.target);
    }));
  }
}

var shownCursorChangeDisposer;
var shownCursorZoomStartedDisposer;
var shownCursorZoomEndedDisposer;

function handleShowCursor(shownCursor) {
  // disable mouse for all other cursors
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var cursor = chart.cursor;
    if (cursor != shownCursor) {
      cursor.interactionsEnabled = false;
    }
    // remove show listener
    cursorShowDisposers[i].dispose();
  }

  // add change disposer to the hovered chart cursor
  shownCursorChangeDisposer = shownCursor.lineX.events.on("positionchanged", function (event) {
    syncCursors(shownCursor);
  });


  shownCursorZoomStartedDisposer = shownCursor.events.on("zoomstarted", function (event) {

    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      var chart = charts[i];
      var cursor = chart.cursor;
      if (cursor != event.target) {
        var point = { x: event.target.point.x, y: 0 };
        cursor.triggerDown(point);
      }
    }
  });

  shownCursorZoomEndedDisposer = shownCursor.events.on("zoomended", function (event) {
    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      var chart = charts[i];
      var cursor = chart.cursor;
      if (cursor != event.target) {
        var point = { x: event.target.point.x, y: 0 };
        cursor.triggerUp(point);
      }
    }
  });


  shownCursor.events.once("hidden", function (event) {
    shownCursorChangeDisposer.dispose();
    shownCursorZoomStartedDisposer.dispose();
    shownCursorZoomEndedDisposer.dispose();

    for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
      var chart = charts[i];
      var cursor = chart.cursor;
      cursor.hide(0);

      cursorShowDisposers[i].dispose();
    }

    initCursorListeners();
  });
}

function syncCursors(syncWithCursor) {
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var cursor = chart.cursor;

    var point = { x: syncWithCursor.point.x, y: 0 };

    if (cursor != syncWithCursor) {
      cursor.triggerMove(point);
    }
  }
}


function syncDateAxes(syncWithAxis) {
  for (var i = 0; i < charts.length; i++) {
    var chart = charts[i];
    var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.getIndex(0);
    if (dateAxis != syncWithAxis) {
      dateAxis.events.disableType("selectionextremeschanged");
      dateAxis.start = syncWithAxis.start;
      dateAxis.end = syncWithAxis.end;
      dateAxis.events.enableType("selectionextremeschanged");
    }
  }
}
;
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With a few small tweaks it is possible to make it stack all three axes in a single chart with the cursor, scrollbar and zooming affecting all three:

- **The main trick is to set `chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = 'vertical'` so that all three axes stack vertically in the container**
- To get this to work, **don't** set `opposite` on any of the axes (we want them all to live on the left)
- Remove the lines setting `minY` and `maxY` values on yAxis to avoid ugly overlapping
- Set a suitable height and margin on each axis like so: `yAxis.height = 150; yAxis.marginBottom = 20;`
- Change the overall height of the chart in the CSS to make it taller and prevent everything squashing together (e.g. `#chartdiv { height: 700px; }`)

Here's a [modified version of your example](https://codepen.io/mattwilson1024/pen/pobvYEG) and (in case that Codepen stops existing) here's the code:

```
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 *
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 *
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Apply chart themes
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;
chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = 'vertical'

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.baseInterval = {
  'timeUnit': 'second',
  'count': 1
};
dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('minute', 'h:mm a');
dateAxis.tooltipDateFormat = '[bold]MM-dd-yy, h:mm:ss a[/]';
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;

chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();


var data = [
  {name:'value1', value: 2, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 8, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 4, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 2, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:15.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 9, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 11, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 6, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:30.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 4, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 5, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 13, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:00:45.00Z'},
  {name:'value1', value: 1, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value2', value: 7, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
  {name:'value3', value: 11, timestamp: '2018-01-01T15:01:00.00Z'},
];
var names = ['value1','value2', 'value3'];

names.forEach((name, index) => {
  var series = this.chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
  var yAxis = this.chart.yAxes.getIndex(index);
  yAxis.height = 150;
  yAxis.marginBottom = 20;
  series.yAxis = yAxis;
  series.name = name;
  series.dataFields.dateX = 'date';
  series.dataFields.valueY = 'value';
  series.data = data.filter(d => d.name === name).map( d => {
    return {date: new Date(d.timestamp), value: d.value};
  });
  switch (name) {
    case 'value1':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#9E842F');
      break;
    case 'value2':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#196D6F');
      break;
    case 'value3':
      series.stroke = am4core.color('#553786');
      break;
  }
  series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
  series.tooltip.background.fill = series.stroke;
  series.tooltipText = '{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]';

  yAxis.cursorTooltipEnabled = false;
  yAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
  yAxis.renderer.line.strokeWidth = 2;
  yAxis.renderer.line.stroke = series.stroke;
  yAxis.renderer.labels.template.fill = series.stroke;
  yAxis.renderer.grid.template.disabled = true;

  var bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
  bullet.width = 5;
  bullet.height = 5;
  bullet.fill = series.stroke;
});

var scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.series.values.forEach(s => {
  scrollbarX.series.push(s);
});
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
chart.scrollbarX.parent = this.chart.bottomAxesContainer;

chart.validateData();
```